# Unable to observe Knockout option selected from multi-select list

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am able to populate a multi-select list using the "options" binding in Knockout in the code below. Now I need to enable a button on the screen only when an option is selected. The problem is that I cannot figure out how to observe whether an option is selected or not. Anyone have an idea?

```
<select size="8" multiple data-bind="options: viewsForClient, optionsValue: 'Value', optionsText: 'Text'"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `selectedOptions` (read the knockout documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html)

then on the button, you can data-bind something like `enable: selectedOptionVariable.length > 0` to enable the button if the selectedOptionsVariable array has a value in it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Going to try this now. I knew there had to be a way to observe the change like there is with other KO bindings....